# Find the most recent location in all providers

Tags: android, time

Does anybody have a way to find the most recent location in all the providers ? 
Because due to this [problem](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=28174#makechanges), we will always get the Network provider one, never the GPS one.

It seems that method : getLastKnownLocation() except for the GPS provider is useless, am I wrong ?

Comment: This seems to be a bug from the Android impl. I'm surprised that nobody elsewhere is having problems with this.